# Type referencing args of variable length

Tags: typescript

I declare a method `useRemote` that accepts a method `fn(...args: any[])`:

```
export function useRemote(fn: (...args: unknown[]) => void) {
 function execute(...args2: Parameters<typeof fn>) {
   fn(...args2) // TODO: how to check args2 same args?
  }
  return { execute }
}
```

I hope that at compile time, TypeScript can infer whether the type and order of args are the same as args2. How to do that?

I use it like this:

```
const { execute } = useRemote(
  (s: string, n: number) => somePromise(s, n)
)
```

Then I want to get：

```
execute("string", 0) // success
execute(0, "string") // failed and show red bottom line
```

but the current code allows both of the above to be compiled.

Comment: You need to make `useRemote` *generic* as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mA2L4W).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: it works! So elegant and simple. Thank you very much for your guidance, can you please post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to make `useRemote()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the callback's [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters), like this:

```
function useRemote<A extends any[]>(fn: (...args: A) => void) {
  function execute(...args2: A) {
    fn(...args2)
  }
  return { execute }
}
```

Here `A` is a generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an array type.  When you call `useRemote`, `A` will be inferred from the parameter list of the `fn` argument:

```
const { execute } = useRemote( 
  (s: string, n: number) => { }
)
```

In the above, `A` is inferred as the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[s: string, n: number]`, and thus the returned `execute` method is of type `(s: string, n: number) => void`.  Meaning you get the desired type checking:

```
execute("string", 0) // success
execute(0, "string") // error!
//      ~ Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwEpoLZymgHgEFE0APfMAExUQEMwBPAbQF0A+ACmDAC5FOAOmF0ATgHMU-IgEpEAXnaIAbnBhU5AbwBQiRKEiwEpMmggh8QkRJQAmaVt179YK4LGTbMpwF8notCgQUSRNEzMLNEQ-P21tCAQUKEQw8gj8aIVkdCxcS0QAegLEEhgwYDRRAKp6WmYpRCTRMvEAGkQ+DpBsACNK1idOBqaW9s6wbr7ROUUU6O1vbTTzSwAiEbBxVfaABjkixpAICDQUFCXTFbROHfb1qGbN1f3iytE4UQBCbQPnPQA-EoSbpoMDJODARBQRgAByiAHIJr1KvDEDBaGA8LUUDBxGA6D0ADZRKBwRAwsR0bCBSqICFQ2EIjbieGCIA)